# SQL update/delete trigger not working properly

Tags: sql, triggers

I have a trigger that is used for auditing inserted, updated and deleted rows. I am having an issue with acquiring the Old Values and New Values from the trigger. The trigger utilizes a loop to insert all values of any row that has been altered in any way (inserted, updated, deleted). However, my code is not returning the values but instead the column names as the values.

Here is part of my code:

```
SELECT @COLNAME = NAME 
FROM SYSCOLUMNS 
WHERE COLID = @FIELD AND
    ID = (SELECT ID FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE NAME = 'FIN_HOTEL_DTL_TYPE') 
SELECT @OLDVAL = SUBSTRING(@COLNAME, 2, LEN(@COLNAME)) FROM DELETED 
SELECT @NEWVAL = SUBSTRING(@COLNAME, 2, LEN(@COLNAME)) FROM INSERTED 
SELECT @MODBY = MODIFIED_BY FROM INSERTED 
SELECT @MODDT = MODIFIED_DATETIME FROM INSERTED
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

T-SQL is just a different world.

Your code is doing exactly what you have told it to do.  @ColName is not a reference to a column object, but a variable holding a string value which you have loaded with the name of a column.

I suggest that you look at an [example](http://web.archive.org/web/20071006100909/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-audit-changes-to-sql-server-data.html).  Read the whole thing if you wish, but if you are in a hurry, drop down to the phrase CREATE TRIGGER Audit.

Also, take the time to do this with set based logic - as in the example.  Harness the power and performance of the DBMS by making use of T-SQL and throwing loose the bonds of row by row coding.  No really.  Coded loops = poor performance.  If needed, the DBMS will implement loops ( or however it wishes ) in the background.

Good luck!

---

I was trying to find this link earlier.  I believe that [this posting](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_nielsen/archive/2007/01/15/codegen-to-create-fixed-audit-trail-triggers.aspx) by Paul Nielsen is pretty close to what you want.

Comment: Yeah I figured as much about the @ColName. I was using this type of logic because some of the tables have extensive amounts of columns (legacy DB, not my choice unfortunately) and i didn't want to have to code each column.

Comment: Beautiful answer, and in particular the part about avoiding doing this in a loop.  I have implemented similar triggers, and they are shorter and simpler without the loop in addition to performing better.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I took the loop out and simply referenced the columns individually.